# Qt Mac - App not restoring after closing

Tags: c++, macos, qt

In Mac when we press the close button apps by default hide to dock. The same happens with my Qt app too, but it does not restore afterwards as expected. There are many posts which provide code to detect click on dock icon.

I don't need to detect, I just want the default functionality, that it should restore.

It restores if I minimize but not on close.

The fix I used is:

```
void myAPP::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    #ifdef Q_OS_MAC
        event->ignore();
        this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized) ;
        return;
    #endif
}
```

It makes it minimize on close and than my app restores properly. But now the issue is that it is preventing shutdown on Mac unless I exit the application. Shutdown makes the app minimize.

I am using `Qt 5.4`

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue, I wanted to know the source of `Close Event`. If source is user than minimize, else if source is `OS shutdown event` than exit.

We can use event->spontaneous() to check that. Following is the working solution:

```
void myAPP::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    #ifdef Q_OS_MAC
        if(event->spontaneous())
        {
            event->ignore();
            this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized) ;
            return;
        }
    #endif
}
```